# What is the limit for reverse-geocode lookups on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to find out the limit for reverse-geocode lookups on iPhone, are they per application/per device and how many per day?  The doco just states:

> MKReverseGeocoder
>
> Each Map Kit application has a limited amount of reverse geocoding capacity, so it is to your advantage to use reverse geocode requests sparingly. Here are some rules of thumb for using this class most effectively:

Comment: Also just for reference, I want to use this to get the user's suburb name when they perform an action in the app (infrequent).

Answer (score 4):

As the MapKit framework uses the Google Map services and the same TOS I would imagine the same limits are applied. In which case the lookups are counted per-ip address (rather than per-app or per-device)

So the limits would be no more than 15,000 geocode requests in a 24 hour period received from a single IP address. Or geocode requests submitted from a single IP address at too fast a rate (in my experience more than 2 a second seems to trigger this...)

Breeching the limits results in the server responding with a status code of 620

See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#geocoder_limit

Comment: updated limits  - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Answer (score 2):

We have found out that that that we cannot return more than 5 geocodes "instantly" using serverside scripting on the free API

Comment: Thanks for your answer - can you be more precise if this limit is per device, per day or any other timespan?